# How to integrate Gkash in a Next.js 14 project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, payment-gateway, payment, next.js13

I was trying to integrate Gkash in my Next.js 14 project, and use the `callbackurl`.

[`callbackurl` documentation](https://doc.gkash.my/web-payments).

My code for the payment gateway redirect:

```
<form className='hidden' id="myForm" method="POST" action="https://api-staging.pay.asia/api/paymentform.aspx">
    <input type="text" name="version" value="1.5.5" readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="CID" value={gkashCID} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_currency" value={currency} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_amount" value={amount} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_cartid" value={orderId} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="signature" value={signature} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="returnurl" value={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_NAME}/purchases/${orderId}/${amount}/${currency}`} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="callbackurl" value={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_NAME}/purchases/${orderId}/${amount}/${currency}`} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_firstname" value={buyerFirstName} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_lastname" value={buyerLastName} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="v_billemail" value={userEmail} readOnly={true} />
    <input type="text" name="clientip" value={clientIP} readOnly={true} />
</form>
```

The issue I get is, after the payment success, it redirects me to the return URL page, but it shows invalid URL as shown below in the images, and after a refresh, the page data loads.

[image: payment confirmed page]

[image: invalid URL page]

The documentation says:

> Print the text "OK" as the HTTP response upon receiving the callback request from Gkash.

But I am not able to catch where to do it.

---

This issue was, in the return URL, i.e.:

```html
<input type="text" name="returnurl" value={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_NAME}/purchases/${orderId}/${amount}/${currency}`} readOnly={true} />
```

So I switched it with:

```html
<input type="text" name="returnurl" value={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_NAME}/api/sendOK`} readOnly={true} />
```

Now it shows this page:

[image: return URL post API call]

How should I hit the callback URL? As it just gets stuck on that post return URL API call page.

Note: I am using Next.js inbuilt API.